# Recursive glob only working on some folders

Tags: python, recursion, search, directory, glob

I'm searching through a hierarchy of folders with:

```
files = glob(os.path.join(fileroot,somefolder,'**/*.npy'),recursive=True)
```

and it works great on some folders and not others. I've tried other methods also:

```
from pathlib import Path

for file_path in Path(os.path.join(fileroot,somefolder)).glob('**/*.npy'):
    print(file_path)
```

Have tried scrapping the 'npy' to see if its finding without the extension and no luck. What am i missing?

I tried moving my folder with the npy files up one directory and that makes them findable..so I'm something with the recursive argument is screwy.

With the recursive glob above I can find files 2 folders deep (i.e., fileroot/somefolder/folder1/folder2/*npy) but not any further (fileroot/somefolder/folder1/folder2/folder3/*npy).

I've also noticed that I have the same results when setting recursive to False, so it seems the recursive command is being ignored for some reason

Comment: Recursive `glob.glob` seems to work fine on my system. It would be awesome if you could update your question to show a reproducible example (e.g., "when my files are organized like this, it doesn't work...").

Comment: i updated the question a bit

Comment: Globbing for `*.npy` will not find `*npy` files.

Comment: Turns out its a file path too long issue, shortening certain folder names makes the recursive search work...annoying

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand the question but this gets filenames in folders and subfolders from a root folder 'test'.

```
from os import walk

path = './test'
my_files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    my_files.extend(filenames)
```

Comment: To emulate `glob` I believe you would need to filter the results using `fnmatch.fnmatch()`.